# JSF2+Hibernate4+Spring3 Integration

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsf

Hi Right now i am using `JSF2+Hibernate` in my web project but I know `Spring` is very popular and powerful framework(i am new in Spring) so i am thinking to integrate `Spring` and `Hibernate4` in my project so i was looking for some demo example in google , but i noticed in maximum places people  used below code for Session initialization

```
public class UserDAO implements IUserDAO {

     private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

     /**
      * Get Hibernate Session Factory
      *
      * @return SessionFactory - Hibernate Session Factory
      */
     public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
      return sessionFactory;
     }

     /**
      * Set Hibernate Session Factory
      *
      * @param SessionFactory - Hibernate Session Factory
      */
     public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
            this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
        }
```

Is this good way to create `SessionFactory` object in each `DAO` class ? Or any better way to handle Database connection? So that no any chance for session mismanagement.Please help me to implement best way .
Thanks

Comment: You are not creating (but injecting) `SessionFactory` in your DAO here. Or do we miss some code?

Comment: I am checking here [link](http://www.java101.net/news/viewnews.xhtml;jsessionid=bef5a2cefc5f376609ce09d2c3ec?id=188)

Comment: That way you let Spring create your `SessionFactory` and inject it for every single DAO that needs it. Spring has built in classes like [LocalSessionFactoryBean](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/LocalSessionFactoryBean.html) which makes easy to inject your customized session factory.

Comment: Also [Here](http://www.onlinetechvision.com/?p=566)

Comment: @XtremeBiker so this is good way and Spring will take care of Open/close or manage the session or DB Connection

Comment: Which server are you using?

Comment: @XtremeBiker i am using Tomcat7

Answer (score 1):

1. Add `BaseDAO`
2. Extend each your DAO (extends `BaseDAO`)
3. Add `sessionFactory` only into `BaseDAO` and make `protected SessionFactory sessionFactory`.

And you will have access to `sessionFactory` from all DAOs which extend `BaseDAO`.

```
abstract public class BaseDAO {
   protected SessionFactory sessionFactory;

   public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
      this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
   }
}

public class UserDAO extends BaseDAO implements IUserDAO {
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it will work.

```
@Transactional
    public class ProductDaoImpl implements ProductDao {
        private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

        @Resource
        public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
            return sessionFactory;
        }

        public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
            this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
        }

        public void save(Product product) {
            Session session = getSessionFactory().openSession();
            try {
                session.save(product);
            } finally {
                session.close();
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Again if you will check You are doing same 'SessionFactory' in each Dao only thing you added '@Transactional' in code no any new thing